# How to get data from entity that exists only in session with Django?

Tags: python, django

I have to store order history as sets of goods in order. I intended to achieve this by copying contents of the cart to model I've created using `object.create`. But cart was written by someone else and doesn't have actual model as it exists only within session. How do I retrieve data from it to put it into my `Order` object?
My cart class:

```
class Cart(object):

    def __init__(self, request):
        """
        Инициализируем корзину
        """
        self.session = request.session
        cart = self.session.get(settings.CART_SESSION_ID)
        if not cart:
            # save an empty cart in the session
            cart = self.session[settings.CART_SESSION_ID] = {}
        self.cart = cart

    def add(self, product, quantity=1, update_quantity=False):
        """
        Добавить продукт в корзину или обновить его количество.
        """
        product_id = str(product.id)
        if product_id not in self.cart:
            self.cart[product_id] = {'quantity': 0,
                                     'price': str(product.price)}
        if update_quantity:
            self.cart[product_id]['quantity'] = quantity
        else:
            self.cart[product_id]['quantity'] += quantity
        self.save()

    def save(self):
        # Обновление сессии cart
        self.session[settings.CART_SESSION_ID] = self.cart
        # Отметить сеанс как "измененный", чтобы убедиться, что он сохранен
        self.session.modified = True

    def remove(self, product):
        """
        Удаление товара из корзины.
        """
        product_id = str(product.id)
        if product_id in self.cart:
            del self.cart[product_id]
            self.save()

    def __iter__(self):
        """
        Перебор элементов в корзине и получение продуктов из базы данных.
        """
        product_ids = self.cart.keys()
        # получение объектов product и добавление их в корзину
        products = Product.objects.filter(id__in=product_ids)
        for product in products:
            self.cart[str(product.id)]['product'] = product

        for item in self.cart.values():
            item['price'] = Decimal(item['price'])
            item['total_price'] = item['price'] * item['quantity']
            yield item

    def __len__(self):
        """
        Подсчет всех товаров в корзине.
        """
        return sum(item['quantity'] for item in self.cart.values())

    def get_total_price(self):
        """
        Подсчет стоимости товаров в корзине.
        """
        return sum(Decimal(item['price']) * item['quantity'] for item in
                   self.cart.values())


    def clear(self):
        # удаление корзины из сессии
        del self.session[settings.CART_SESSION_ID]
        self.session.modified = True
```

Comment: Just create a Model matching the data in cart. Or if you don't want to do that just serialize the data and store it as a JSONField.

Answer (score 0):

It's not in this class you need to look but where it is used.
If I was you, I will look to store the object created in `request.session["cart"]` to reuse it, or you can use it in a redirect.
It's just a beginner idea who does like that on his websites.

If anyone has a better idea...